# Best Caching for a Chatting System

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, apache, caching

I created a chatting website that gives real time chat like messenger. I do this by using setinterval to spit out latest messages and notifs from my other php files.

```
messageRefresh = setInterval(() => {
            $.post('includes/ajax-func/getchat-afunc.php', {
                         outgoingUsersId : sender,
                         incomingUsersId : receiver,
                         newMsgCount : msgCount
                      }, function (response) {
                          $(messageSection).html(response);
                 });
          }, 500
  );
```

But there is a warning in DOM saying these errors:

[image: 1st]
[image: 2nd]
[image: 3rd]

How to eradicate this errors and what cache format (eg. max-age, no-cache, etc.) should I use?

Comment: Aside from the question, you should not be using AJAX polling for a chat system - it doesn't scale and has lots of drawbacks such as delayed delivery. Research Websockets and use this for real-time chat instead. Depending on concurrency requirements you could potentially use something like Redis for caching each new message, and reading from the cache to populate message history when a user connects

Comment: What if he uses long-polling?? It will be nearly realtime. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Long polling still has scale issues. Using the observer pattern with websockets is by far the best approach here. However it's a trade off between dev time, estimated usage and client expectation.

Comment: How does facebook implement its chatting system? that there are no ajax request every second shown in network tab